# What happened to Hermione’s clothing and other possessions after the memory wipe in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

What happened to Hermione’s clothing and other possessions after she wiped her parents’ memories of her? And what about those empty picture frames?

Comment: Discussion about edits to this question and book/movie scope have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90165/discussion-on-question-by-dottie-what-happened-to-hermiones-clothing-and-other). Dottie, please could you clarify whether you're interested only in the movies or also in what happened in the books?

Answer (score 15):

**Note:  This answer refers to the book only; the 'empty picture frames' are seen in the movie, but not found / referenced in the book.**

Nothing; they are likely still in her closet / dresser / etc.  Her parents picked up and moved to Australia.  If her parents owned their home (not unlikely) and Hermione took the time to think things through and prepare (quite likely, given that this is, after all, Hermione), their home is probably mothballed and waiting for them to come home.

She did take the time to plan this out, charm her parents, and pack ("for days"), so I can't see her not having taken precautions with regards to their home and her possessions.

Her picture is still in all of the frames; the pictures are just still back at the house.

> “Let’s see,” said Hermione, slamming Travels with Trolls onto the
>   discarded pile with a rather fierce look. “I’ve been packing for days,
>   so we’re ready to leave at a moment’s notice, which for your
>   information has included doing some pretty difficult magic, not to
>   mention smuggling Mad-Eye’s whole stock of Polyjuice Potion right
>   under Ron’s mum’s nose.
>
> “I’ve also modified my parents’ memories so
>   that they’re convinced they’re really called Wendell and Monica
>   Wilkins, and that their life’s ambition is to move to Australia, which
>   they have now done. That’s to make it more difficult for Voldemort to
>   track them down and interrogate them about me—or you, because
>   unfortunately, I’ve told them quite a bit about you.
>
> “Assuming I
>   survive our hunt for the Horcruxes, I’ll find Mum and Dad and lift the
>   enchantment. If I don’t—well, I think I’ve cast a good enough charm to
>   keep them safe and happy. Wendell and Monica Wilkins don’t know that
>   they’ve got a daughter, you see.”

Comment: FWIW, I think the "empty picture frames" referred to [the movie scene](https://youtu.be/-H0JParMivs?t=67).

Comment: @Jenayah -- Excellent point; I've never seen the movies.  I've amended my answer to be specific to the book.

Comment: That scene still makes no sense to me - I get the pictures where it was Hermione with her parents or something and now it's just the parents - but the pictures where she was the only person in them - now it's like "Hey, why did we frame this picture of the couch again?"  I had the same problem with that photo in Back to the Future where the kids were disappearing and it was just a photo of the side of the house that nobody would ever take...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, it's symbolic made just for the movies. Obliviate can wipe memories, not erase photos. However, for an emotional movie scene, showing the photos being erased helped drive the point across.

Also, magic.

Comment: From the quotes you provided (especially “their life’s ambition is to move to Australia, which they have now done“) isn’t it much more likely that they sold their home and took all their possessions with them to Australia? It’s what I’d mean by moving. (In fact, how would they afford it without selling their home?) Of course this doesn’t answer the question of what happened to Hermione’s stuff.

Comment: @GuyShapter - No, you have it wrong. In the movies the spell literally erased the photos. It wasn't symbolism.

Comment: @11684 - That's not an unreasonable point, but given what we know of Hermione, AND the fact that she is factoring in possibly undoing it later, I would wager that she took steps to preserve things, including ownership of the house.  That's just my opinion (based on her character), but it SEEMS in character.  Failing that, other possibilities exist; rendering the house unplotable, and just leaving it alone, for example.

Comment: @K-H-W Of course that’s possible, but it’s not supported by the provided quote. If we’re speculating, I would find it a lot more plausible if Hermione put her possessions in magical storage (vanishing/conjuring seems to do this but I bet there are other ways) and then let her parents move the Muggle way (taking everything else back and forth to Australia).

Comment: Hey @Valorum, in the movies, the photo frames (physically) being erased of Hermione is *symbolic* of Hermione being erased from her parent's lives. This was used as a visual medium in the movies. Another way they could have done this was "Obliviate", some confused looks along with a parent asking "who are you", but personally I like the imagery of the erased photos.

Comment: @11684 - I disagree that it's not supported by the quote -- why would they have sold the Granger's house -- they are the Wilkins family.  If they own their house (and for two dentists to do so is not unlikey), it's not implausible for her to just mothball the house, while the are off living other lives.

Comment: @GuyShapter - If you cast your eyeballs down a few inches you'll find a quote directly from the script. It confirms that the photoframes were literally going blank *from Hermione's own perspective*. Since she remembers her parents (she didn't obliviate herself), that means that the magic somehow wiped the frames rather than just tricking her parents into not seeing her in them.

Comment: It's possible to rent out your home in the UK leaving it in the hands of a management company and live on the proceeds overseas. Particularly as UK property prices and rents are so much larger than many other countries.

Comment: @Sarriesfan - Another viable option.  I like the idea of our favorite witch doing it via magic, i.e. making the house Un-plotable, etc., but your idea could work, as well, with only mild magic used to befuddle a Mgt. company rep., and might make more sense for a Muggle Born like our heroine to think of.

Answer (score 8):

The [movie script](https://www.gazette-du-sorcier.com/IMG/pdf/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows_-_Part_1.pdf) indicates that as well as modifying her parent's memories, magic also took care of the evidence of her physical existence in the house.

Note that ***from Hermione's perspective***, her image is *actually disappearing* from the photo frames.

> HERMIONE: Obliviate.
>
> Mrs. Granger’s face goes briefly slack and she reaches
> out, as if to break a fall, then, slowly, her hand drops,
> coming to rest upon her husband’s. He blinks once,
> blankly, and then... enfolds her fingers in his.
> **Hermione lowers her arm and, eyes stinging with tears,
>
> watches the PHOTOGRAPHS placed about the room begin to
>
> CHANGE. One by one, Hermione DISAPPEARS from each.**

In the novel we don't learn what happened to her personal effects but we do know that Hermione is perfectly capable of using magic to make objects fly, transfigure and disappear, any of which could be used to take any incongruous artifacts out of the house.